# Java EE MVC without framework

Tags: java, model-view-controller, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee

I am working on a Java project to run on Google App Engine. I started with coding in JSP/Servlets. Now after few classes, I am seriously thinking about using an MVC framework.

My question is, is there a best way to code a simple MVC framework? I understand, the best approach is to choose one (Spring MVC/Slim/Play etc).

But I want to learn about best practices to use MVC without a framework.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541077/design-patterns-web-based-applications/

Comment: Any info on implementing support for AJAX would be helpful too.

Answer (score 1):

i'm a framework learner, but for me, framework is just something that can simplify your coding.
And if you know how those frameworks work, you may try to implement the process yourself by simulating with your own codes. Though there may be many bugs in your code, it's worth trying~